# jQuery selectmenu wordpress

Tags: wordpress, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, wordpress-theming

I am moving a site from normal php to wordpress and currently they use jquery-selectmenu plugin for their select menus.

I have tried to enqueu the script in wordpress head with no luck.

The scripts from the previous site look as follows.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $siteurl; ?>css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.8.1.custom.css" type="text/css" /> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $siteurl; ?>js/select-menu.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $siteurl; ?>js/init.js"></script>
```

**init.js** simply calls the function and works

```
$(function(){
    $('select#speedC').selectmenu({style:'dropdown'});
});
```

Now in Wordpress i added the following to my head.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' ); ?>/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.8.1.custom.css" />
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>" />

<?php wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-core' ); ?>
<?php wp_enqueue_script( 'swfobject' ); ?>
<?php wp_enqueue_script( 'ui-core-select', get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/js/select-menu.js' ); ?>
<?php wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-pajinate', get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/js/jquery.pajinate.js' ); ?>
<?php wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui', get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/js/jquery-ui.1.7.2.min.js' ); ?>
```

And the script in my page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $j=jQuery.noConflict();

    // Use jQuery via $j(...)
    $j(document).ready(function(){
        $j('select#speedC').selectmenu({style:'dropdown'});
    });
</script>
```

Any ideas why it is not initiating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some more research I found that the existing library is not currently kept up to date and not playing well with jQuery.

From now on refer to this one [jQuery.ui.selectmenu.js](https://github.com/fnagel/jquery-ui)

Comment: Please note there is a upcoming official version: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/tree/selectmenu

Comment: The `jquery-ui-selectmenu` in Wordpress is 1.11.4 currently, which is a newer version. There must be some other reason it glitches in Wordpress. The one you link hasn't been updated in a couple years.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question but adding this as it appears high up in Google and may help others.

Most of the jQuery UI components are included with WordPress but are not enqueued by default, you need to enqueue them with this.

```
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-selectmenu' );
```

There's a helpful list of the included components and the enqueue string at http://jafty.com/blog/tag/how-to-use-jquery-ui-in-wordpress/